# FPGA Board to buy? Nexys3 or Nexys4

Tags: fpga

I was considering buying a Nexys board to learn about digital electronics. The famous ones I see are the Nexys3, and Nexys4. Can someone suggest based on usage, which is better.

Also, some other sites seem to carry FPGA boards like Mojo, and Cyclone 4, Papillo .

What factor should I keep in mind before placing an order?
Thank You for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just learning HDL and FPGA's, I suggest the major factor in your first board is the available educational material.

I personally learned with the [Basys 2](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=BASYS2) and this [free course by Hamster](http://hamsterworks.co.nz/mediawiki/index.php/FPGA_course). It is written for the [Basys 2](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=BASYS2) and [Nexys 2](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,789&Prod=NEXYS2) board (both Spartan 3E boards). The course goes through the all aspects of those boards, from the leds to the on board ram, to VGA output. The course uses VHDL which I suggest learning but of course this is my bias as I have not used Verilog (Verilog seems lower class to me and is the vibe I get from any FPGA tutorials, articles, etc).

Keep in mind, that the course can be used with any board that uses Xilinx, but you will need to figure out your own constraints file. The constraints file connects your VHDL to your board peripherals.

I have since bought a more expensive and better board ([Atlys](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,836&Prod=ATLYS) Spartan 6) but I haven't used it much and I just seem to use my Basys 2 for everything so don't worry about buying something at the Spartan 3E level.

---

The second factor is the available toolchain. I have only used Xilinx and Digilent boards but they seem great and you can get Xilinx WebPack which is completely free. I have not used Altera stuff at all but my bias is Xilinx.

---

Another factor, is the peripherals and IO available on the board. This includes: switches, buttons, LEDs, IO, VGA, ethernet, etc. This allows you to experiment with all sorts of projects without having to get external parts set up right.

Comment: Thanks! wouldn't Buying Nexys3 than Nexys2 be better? as its new and has more functionality and processing?

Comment: @Sherby Yes, especially if you can get the academic pricing. Just a note: You will have to figure out the constraints for the projects if you follow that course. If you scroll down on that page, you can find the "Master UCF File for Nexys3" which will contain all constraints that you can copy from.

Comment: I just realized Nexys2 is more expensive than Nexys3. Why is the 2nd version more expensive?

Comment: @Sherby It costs more to make... But the Nexys 3 is a better board and cheaper. I still recommend the Basys 2.